# Mathematica integration error

Tags: warning-messages

`Integrate[Integrate[Abs[Exp[2*Pi*I*x] + Exp[2*Pi*I*y]], {x, 0, 1}], {y, 0, 1}]` yields `0` as result.

This cannot be correct, because the integrand is positive and nonzero in the indicated region.

Wolfram Alpha sais: `Standard computation time exceeded`, so I do not know if there the same comes out.

Any idea what is going on?

Answer (score 2):

You can express the integrand in a different way :

```
FullSimplify[ComplexExpand[Abs[Exp[2*Pi*I*x] + Exp[2*Pi*I*y]], TargetFunctions -> {Re, Im}]]
(* 2 Sqrt[Cos[\[Pi] (x - y)]^2] *)
```

Now

```
Integrate[2 Sqrt[Cos[\[Pi] (x - y)]^2], {x, 0, 1}]
(* 0 *)
```

but

```
Integrate[2 Abs[Cos[\[Pi] (x - y)]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
(* 4/\[Pi] *)

NIntegrate[Abs[Exp[2*Pi*I*x] + Exp[2*Pi*I*y]], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
(* 1.27324 *)
```

So the square root seems to be the root of the problem.

Comment: Since the integral is on the unit square, just include the assumptions {0<=x<=1, 0<=y<=1} in `Simplify`. `expr = Abs[Exp[2*Pi*I*x] + Exp[2*Pi*I*y]] // ComplexExpand // Simplify[#, {0 <= x <= 1, 0 <= y <= 1}] &` gives `2*Abs[Cos[Pi*(x - y)]]` and, as you showed, `Integrate[expr, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]` gives `4/Pi`.

Comment: @BobHanlon Thanks.

Comment: you need only the assumption `Element[{x, y}, Reals]` ( adding that assumption to `Integrate` does not fix the original anomaly though )

Comment: Integrate[
 Simplify[ComplexExpand[
   Abs[Exp[2*Pi*I*x] + Exp[2*Pi*I*y]]], {x, y} \[Element] Reals], {x, 
  0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}] -> 4/pi